# I want one table to inherit from another

Tags: sql, postgres-9.6

I have 2 SQL tables say `all_cities`, `regular_cities`, (and `capitol_cities`).

`all_cities` has 2 columns : `name`, `population`
`regular_cities` has 2 columns : `name`, `population`
`capitol_cities` has 3 columns : `name`, `population`, `state`

These tables are already created. I want to connect them using table partitioning but first I need to make sure that tables `regular_cities` and `capitol_cities` inherit from `all_cities`.

Is there anyway to have these tables inherit from another table even after the tables are created or only when creating a new table?

Comment: WHat do you mean by "connect them [the tables] using table partitioning?

Comment: Are you looking to add a `foreign key` constraint?

Answer (score 1):

After searching around the correct way to do this is with a simple ALTER statement
`ALTER TABLE <child_table> INHERIT <parent_table>;`
That's it!

Documentation here
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html